# What OpenCourseWare courses use Lua?

Tags: resources, lua

I would really like to use OpenCourseWare videos to learn how to be a better programmer, but I have only found videos from universities which use Python, JAVA, and Lisp. Are there any university courses which use Lua as the primary language to teach programming basics or methodology?

Comment: I'm surprised. You correctly identified that Lua is a proper name (ie: no ALL CAPS), but you ALL CAPS'd *Java*, which is also a proper name. Usually, we get people thinking Lua is an acronym.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try youtube?

http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=lua+programming+tutorial